# Remove leading zero from time of day in Matplotlib DateFormatter

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I use a Matplotlib DateFormatter, like this:

```
mydateformatter = DateFormatter("%b %d %I:%M %p", self._tz)
```

I'll get dates like (note the time part has a leading zero):

**Nov 27 2011
 03:00 PM**

Instead, I'd like to lose the leading zero on times (more human that way), like:

**Nov 27 2011
  3:00 PM**

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note: see the edit history to understand the discussion in the comments below. This post has been rewritten to reflect them.**

It can't be done using the standard date conversion specifiers, which are listed in the python docs (the same ones as standardized by C). However, there may be platform dependent ways to accomplish this format. A bit of code like this might come in handy:

```
# Set the default spec to use -- uglier is better than broken.
hour_fmt = '%I'

# If we're running on a platform that has an hour spec w/o leading zero
# then use that one instead.
if sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
    hour_fmt = '%l'
elif sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    hour_fmt = '%#I'
# etc

mydateformatter = DateFormatter("%b %d " + hour_fmt + ":%M %p", self._tz)
```

I have confirmed `%l` to work on Linux and the OP has confirmed  '%#I` to work on Windows.

Comment: Where are you getting %l from?  On the strftime page I see (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strftime.htm) there is no such directive.  Anyway, this didn't work; instead, I got times without any hours place at all, so like:  "Nov 24 20122 :35 PM"

Comment: Very interesting -- Actually, I cheated a little and used the man page for the C `strftime()` function which has more or less the same formatting as `time.strftime()` in python. I should point out, that it does work for me using `time.strftime()`, despite the fact that the python docs don't mention it either (!). I'm uinsg Python 2.7.2. The `matplotlib` docs seemed to indicate that it would use `strftime`.

Comment: Aha... according to the docs: "Additional directives may be supported on certain platforms, but only the ones listed here have a meaning standardized by ANSI C." In other words, the `strftime()` for your platform may not support `%l`. Will update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for the additional homework!  Hmm, as I need this to work on Windows, I'll have to find a different approach.

Comment: According to MSDN, their `strftime()` accepts `%#I` for this purpose. Not sure if it'll work, but it can't hurt to try.

Comment: Works!  Thanks very much!  Looks much nicer.  So do you think, then, that for creating a cross-platform app I'll need to implement separate rules for Linux, Windows, and Mac on this?  (I can test on Linux but currently I'm not set up to do that).  I accepted your answer; maybe you can edit it to include this platform-dependent help?

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it worked. I'll go ahead and update the post to reflect this.